# php+mysql account management software?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mysql, open-source

I need an account system added to my website as a plugin to all of my HTML pages. The account system plugin needs to,register new users, log in current users, remove users who want to disconnect service, and manipulate all of these things via database on my web server.

However, I do not know how to program in the PHP language or create and manipulate MySQL databases. I want a program that can create and manipulate the MySQL database automatically for my website and handle also PHP calls automatically.

Are there any open source freeware programs out there that i can use? If so what are the names of these freeware?

Comment: There are hundreds of different options available here. Perhaps if you could be a bit more specific about what you are trying to achieve, we could recommend something that is perfectly tailored to your needs. Why/for what exactly do you want a user registration system if you are unable to program PHP?

Comment: cant really get what you mean, but are you looking for phpMyAdmin?

Comment: i have a website with plenty of pages. i need to some repeating snippet of code that allows a login/signup/logout button at the top right hand corner that does,well just that. i need all of the database work and php that talks to the html to be handled behind the scenes preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called  CMS (Content Management System).
[There are many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP) content management systems that were implemented using PHP\MySql.
The three most popular that I know of, are [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com) (which is used mainly for blogs), [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) and [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/). All the three support user-management, plus, there are thousands of plugins that you can freely download and install!

Comment: Would you be able to share which CMS systems have plugins that are free to use for information *not* hosted on their servers?  For example, like you said it looks like WordPress account management is only for protecting information in your blogs, but what if you have a general website where you want to support user logins, but not roll your own code to do it?

Comment: @Dave I'm sure there are plenty, for example: http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/

Answer (score 0):

I just Googled `php user manager` UserCake showed up first and it's features are below. There are other open source applications written in php which do this. But all require some level of knowledge on your part to create the mysql database and install the script.

```
Login
Register
Lost password recovery
Update password
Update user email
Email templates (optional)
SHA1 security + Salt / Hash
Account activation (optional)
Resend activation email (optional)
User groups (Basic, id - group_name)
Multilingual support
```

Comment: This looks pretty useful, I'm definitely going to check it out!